Methods to calculate discord
I am looking to calculate the discord in an interacting of n spin 1 systems, the Hilbert space being $\mathcal{H_1}\otimes\mathcal{H_2}...\otimes\mathcal{H_n}$ where $\mathcal{H_s}$ for $s=1,...,n$ is the space of a single three level spin 1. I would like to calculate the discord between the subsystems $\mathcal{H_1}\otimes\mathcal{H_2}...\otimes\mathcal{H_{n-1}}$ and $\mathcal{H_n}$, however all of the algorithms I've found to calculate discord are for multiqubit or mulltiqubit systems with one qudit. Since calculating discord is essentially a minimization problem, I was wondering if there is any sort of gradient descent algorithms that works in the space of POVM operators that can be used to calculate discord in the general case.
Edit: One can search the space of POVM operators of a space of dimension $d$ in the following manner:
WLOG start with the set of canonical projectors $P = \{|j\rangle\langle j|$ for $j=1,2,...,d\}$. One can reach another set of POVM operators $P'$ by applying unitary operators $e^{iA}$ and $e^{iB}$ to each projector in $P$, i.e. $P'=\{e^{iA}|j\rangle\langle j|e^{iB}$ for $j=1,2,...,d\}$ where $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian. Any $d\times d$ Hermitian operator can be decomposed as a linear combination of the $d^2-1$ generators of $SU(d)$ plus identity. This gives a $d^2$-dimensional vector of real parameters. Assuming that any set of POVM operators can be transformed into another using the method above, this gives a search space over $2d^2$ real parameters over which you could find the set of POVMs which maximize the classical correlations.
2nd Edit: The above does not cover the entire set of POVMs since the set $P'=\{e^{iA_j}|j\rangle\langle j|e^{iB}$ for $j=1,2,...,d\}$ where the Hermitian matrices $A_j$ could in principle differ for each operator in the set. I'm now less certain the space of POVMs can be covered by applying unitary transformations to the set $\{|j\rangle\langle j|\}_j$.
